# How to submit an add-in to AppSource that requires an authentication with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins, office-store

I'm developing an add-in that integrates with a product of the company that i work. So to use the add-in the customer need to have a system login which Microsoft would not have.

What are the guidelines for submitting an add-in of this nature?

Must i indicate something in the manifest file?

```
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.2">
        <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="" />
  </DefaultSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like our Enterprise policies may be applicable to your scenario. Please see [this blog post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/office-store-validation-policy-changes-to-support-apps-and-add-ins-that-target-larger-organizations-and-enterprises/) for more information.

When you are ready to submit to AppSource, you will need to ensure you provide a system login in the test notes to ensure the validation team can fully test your submission.